# Разбираюсь с usb4java

Tags: java, usb

Пытаюсь разобраться с примером приведённым  [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28712814/how-todetect-usb-vendor-id-and-product-id-using-java)
Скачал отсюда библиотеку [usb4java](http://usb4java.org/)

```
import org.usb4java.Context;
import org.usb4java.Device;
import org.usb4java.DeviceDescriptor;
import org.usb4java.DeviceList;
import org.usb4java.LibUsb;
import org.usb4java.LibUsbException;

public class Main {
    public static int vid = 402;
    public static int pid = 5661;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ExceptionInInitializerError {
        Context context = new Context();
        int result = LibUsb.init(context);
        if (result != LibUsb.SUCCESS) {
            throw new LibUsbException("Unable to initialize the usb device", result);
        }
        DeviceList list = new DeviceList();
        result = LibUsb.getDeviceList(null, list);
        if (result < 0) throw new LibUsbException("Unable to get device list", result);
        try {
            for (Device device : list) {
                DeviceDescriptor device_descriptor = new DeviceDescriptor();
                result = LibUsb.getDeviceDescriptor(device, device_descriptor);
                if (result != LibUsb.SUCCESS) throw new LibUsbException("Unable to get device descriptor : ", result);
                System.out.println("Product id is : " + device_descriptor.idProduct() + " " + "Vendor id is : " + device_descriptor.idVendor());
                if (device_descriptor.idProduct() == pid && device_descriptor.idVendor() == vid) {
                    System.out.println("Product id and vendor id was matched");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Product id and vendor id was not matched");
                }
            }
        } finally {
            LibUsb.freeDeviceList(list, true);
        }
    }
}
```

На строке int result = LibUsb.init(context); выдаёт ошибку, Как её можно устранить?

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
>   at prog.Main.main(Main.java:15)
>   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>   at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
>   Caused by: org.usb4java.LoaderException: Native library not found in    classpath: /org/usb4java/windows-x86_64/libusb-1.0.dll
>   at org.usb4java.Loader.extractLibrary(Loader.java:281)
>   at org.usb4java.Loader.load(Loader.java:356)
>   at org.usb4java.LibUsb.(LibUsb.java:640)
>   ... 6 more

Comment: У вас же написано, что нативная библиотека не найдена в класспафе

Comment: @AndrewBystrov как понимаю мне надо найти эту dll. Вот только куда её надо ? в jar библиотеку usb4java или где то в C:\?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте положить libusb-1.0.dll в system32 для x86 или в SysWow64.
Ну или в то место, в которое указывает class_path

Comment: Спасибо, положил в библиотеку usb4java этот файл и заработало